# word 2010 macro to replace underlined text with auto-incremented text

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I'm trying to replace all instances of underlined text in a document with numbered gaps. For some reason the below gives me overflow error:

```
Sub gapNumber()
Dim myNumber As Integer
gapCount = 1

With ActiveDocument.Content.find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Font.Underline = True
    Do While .Execute( _
        replace:=wdReplaceOne, _
        ReplaceWith:="(" & gapCount & ")", _
        Forward:=True) = True

        gapCount = gapCount + 1

    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing nothing. 
I think where was errors in method execute!
To correct infinite cycling  one of method is to change font.underline=false when replace:

```
    Do While .Execute( _
    Replace:=wdReplaceOne, _
    ReplaceWith:="(" & gapcount & ")", _
    Forward:=True)
.Replacement.Font.Underline = False
    gapcount = gapcount + 1

Loop
```